# kubernetes specification for autoscaling/v2beta2

Tags: kubernetes

In this blog here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#algorithm-details

There is a blurb:

> For object metrics and external metrics, a single metric is fetched, which describes the object in question. This metric is compared to the target value, to produce a ratio as above. In the autoscaling/v2beta2 API version, this value can optionally be divided by the number of pods before the comparison is made.

I need to do exactly this; divide my current metric by the current number of pods.

Where can I find the specification for this API? I have googled frantically to see what the autoscaling yaml specification is to do this but I cannot find it. IE I need to write the autoscaler resource as part of our helm chart.

Answer (score 1):

The specification for k8s API can be found here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/

The above is for k8s version 1.18, you'll have to switch to the right version for you.

The spec for HPA v2beta2 would be here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#horizontalpodautoscaler-v2beta2-autoscaling